# Can the creator of a fictional universe get their own lore wrong?

Tags: warcraft, authors

I'm uncertain if this has been asked before, or if I'm asking it on the correct exchange. If it's misplaced I apologize.

My friend (who is a self-proclaimed Warcraft lore buff) and I were watching a trailer for a World of Warcraft expansion (I believe it to be Warlords of Draenor) and at some point he mentioned that they (Blizzard) got an event wrong, as he watched the scene play out differently during his time with Warcraft 3.

This got me thinking, is it possible for Blizzard to incorrectly portray an event that occurred in a Universe that they are the authors of, or would the latest portrayal of an event essentially "overwrite" their previous portrayal, since they're the creators of the event in the first place?

Comment: Anyone can get anything wrong.

Comment: It's called a retcon. http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Retcon

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fziRzD05yI

Comment: That particular cinematic is *deliberately* wrong, actually... it's showing an event that has changed due to time shenanigans.

Comment: This site ([scifi.se]) very much likes to base everything on "canon", be it author interviews or quotes from the actual work. Dealing with contradictions between different parts of canon often requires a sort of doublethink, and people don't usually explain *why* "canon" should be taken for granted, as it's just a base assumption on this site. I don't know how your question will fare here, but ***if*** it gets closed, [literature.se] might take it or something similar; people there can be more open-minded on "canon" and able to explain why this or that kind of evidence should(n't) be accepted.

Comment: Is this questions specifically about *Warcraft* in particular, or a general question about if Word of God takes precedence over established canon?

Comment: It's a question more geared toward whether the Word of God would take precedence over established canon.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification & suggestion @Randal'Thor

Comment: In my experience with the Warcraft games, *every subsequent game* has retconned at least a couple of things from previously established lore.

Comment: Honestly, I think this would be a perfectly valid question if it asked if this particular seeming error was indeed a continuity error.

Comment: Yes.  The creator can make a mistake.  Anyone who has ever read Isaac Asimov's The Stars Like Dust and The Currents of Space knows The Stars Like Dust has to happen in a much earlier period of Galactic History than The Currents of Space.  But in the preface or introduction to Prelude to Foundation Asimov listed all the books in the series in the order of their fictional chronology, and put The Currents of Space before The Stars Like Dust.  No doubt Asimov corrected that mistake in later editions if and when it was noticed.

Comment: Similarly, I have noted a contradiction in the chronology of Frodo, Sam, and Gollum crossing the mountain into Mordor between the chapters in The Two Towers and Lord of the Rings, and the Tale of the Years in the appendixes to the Lord of the Rings.  And I have had to resort to time travel and alternate universes to explain contradictions in the Sherlock Holmes stores.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots except as OP stated in the comments on the answer, this question is more about the general idea of authors/creators getting things wrong, and not specifically about THIS instance.

Comment: @phantom42: {nods} But, if they were willing to change it... :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Warlords of Draenor involves alternate reality time-travel shenanigans.**

*World of Warcraft* has always played loosely with the lore, and Blizzard is not above [retconning](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Retcon) something if they think they can make it cooler by redoing a concept differently, sometimes yes, accidentally (see: Draenei's race origins, which creator Chris Metzen [apologized for](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Metzen_on_lore) but pushed forward with some success), and sometimes deliberately (see: *Chronicles*, and other major variations on Azeroth's and Titans backstories, etc).  They do have that right, it is their creation, and players and fans can choose which version they preferred, that's their right with their opinions.

That said, the concept behind the *Warlords of Draenor* expansion is that the war criminal Garrosh Hellscream, former Warchief of the Horde, has with help escaped to an alternate timeline version of the Orcs original homeworld of Draenor, long before Garrosh was born or the orcs invaded Azeroth.  In the original timeline, the Orcs are enslaved into a blood pact with demons, by drinking the blood of the pit lord Mannoroth, believing the promises of the warlock Gul'dan and thirsting for ultimate power.  In this new universe that Garrosh escapes to, he contacts his father Grom to warn him of Gul'dan's plot to take control, completely changing that sequence of events and leading Grom to forge a new Iron Horde wielding advanced machinery supplied by Garrosh's knowledge of the future.  They then try to invade Garrosh's old reality, bringing the real world and the player characters into the mix.

The cinematic for that expansion is showing the exact turning point of this new timeline - Grom, instead of being the first to drink, refuses in epic fashion and ambushes Gul'dan and Mannoroth instead.  Then it also (this might be what your friend remembers) deliberately invokes and changes a cinematic from Warcraft III - the original Grom Hellscream, in that game, killed Mannoroth and died from the resulting explosion, redeeming himself and freeing the Orcs from the blood pact.  Here, he kills Mannoroth to prevent that from ever occurring, and Garrosh is able to push him clear just before that explosion takes him out.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation! My question is a more general question regarding authors and whether it's possible for them to modify their own canon to he extent that it's "incorrect." But this is valuable regardless, as I now have an explanation for my friend.

Comment: @MarcCilliers The broader question is going to, unfortunately, depend on the creators, and is likely to be closed on that basis.  Certain setting are pretty loose or non-existant with canon (anything Blizzard, *Doctor Who*), other creators try for a strict canon but leave lots of holes to patch (lets face it, much of *Harry Potter*), and others have a lot of skill and putting down a firm canon but leaving enough room for future plots and reinterpretations of those rules.  So, no one answer, and it depends greatly.  Glad I could help regardless though.